# LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, gnu

I'm trying to compile a test file:

```
gcc -o test  test.c -lg2c
```

but I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lg2c
```

If I use:

```
gcc -o test  test.c -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6 -lg2c
```

then it works fine.

So I added the path like so:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and when I use `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it's listed there, but:

```
gcc -o test  test.c -lg2c
```

still doesn't work, it gives the same error, I can't figure out why.

I'm using CentOS (2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64), any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**: compiler version:

```
rpm -qa | grep gcc

gcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64
compat-gcc-34-g77-3.4.6-19.el6.x86_64
libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64
compat-gcc-34-3.4.6-19.el6.x86_64
gcc-gfortran-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64
libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.i686
gcc-c++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64
```

---

**EDIT**: I tried using `LIBRARY_PATH` instead, now I get a different error:

```
gcc: spec failure: unrecognized spec option 'M'
```

I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`.

Comment: Please tell which gcc version you are using.

Comment: version is gcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64

Comment: Looks like a pathing issue. Can you please provide output of this command: find / -name libg2c 2>/dev/null Also this could be helpful too: yum provides */libg2c.so

Comment: It might be a good idea to update your `ld.so.conf` with the path(s) to the compiler-specific libraries so you don't have to mess with LD_*_PATH for every single program you compile...

Comment: ty for replies, find / -name libg2c 2>/dev/null gives me no output at all. I can't use yum as I don't have root access on this machine.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to linux, how do I go about updating ld.so.conf ?

Comment: @Lefti Well, since you've mentioned you don't have `root` access, that's a moot point - it's usually in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. In some distros, there's also a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory so individual packages/applications can add fragments without modifying one monolithic file.

Comment: Make sure you export the assigned shell variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` otherwise your executable won't be able to find it at runtime: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try setting `LIBRARY_PATH`, instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

From the `gcc` man page:

> LIBRARY_PATH
>
> The value of LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list of directories,
>   much like PATH.  When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the
>   directories thus specified when searching for special linker files, if
>   it can't find them using GCC_EXEC_PREFIX.  Linking using GCC also uses
>   these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the -l
>   option (but directories specified with -L come first).

Comment: OK, I tried that, but now I get: <code>gcc: spec failure: unrecognized spec option 'M'
gcc: spec failure: unrecognized spec option 'M'<\code>

Comment: thanks, this seems to have done it, the spec error turned out to be unrelated.

Comment: Hi Lefti, I actually do not have the LIBRARY_PATH problem, but the "unrelated" spec failure (on a gcc 4.7.2). How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after modifying it. Otherwise GCC won't be able to  see the modified version.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gcc -o test test.c -lg2c
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have done this but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder inside your home directory (not root directory!).
Copy all the required library associated with `-lg2c` from `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6` to this folder.

Set the path in your bash profile to this new folder.

I also got this issue, and solve it with this workaround.
Perhaps we (as non-root users) don't have the necessary access/right to `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6`