# Dependency Hell: linux .so plugin dynamic loading

Tags: c++, linux, dependencies, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading

I've created a shared library built with a standalone build tree using linuxbrew, which fails to load in the parent application due to dependency conflict. I'm using a separate application which dynamically loads the library after startup with the Qt5 QLibrary class.

My library is `libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so`. Both it and the parent app depend on glibc and libstdc++. All of the main app's dependencies are in `/usr/lib`, while all my library's dependencies are in `~/.linuxbrew/lib`.

When the parent application goes to load the `.so` failed I debugged the failure with `LD_DEBUG=all "$dirname/$appname"` and found the following error report in the output:

```
  2610: file=/home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0];  dynamically loaded by libQt5Core.so.5 [0]
  2610: file=/home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0];  generating link map
  2610:   dynamic: 0x00007fd063cff570  base: 0x00007fd063ae7000   size: 0x000000000021a6a8
  2610:     entry: 0x00007fd063af1150  phdr: 0x00007fd063ae7040  phnum:                  5
  2610: 
  2610: checking for version `GCC_3.0' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0] required by file /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0]
  2610: checking for version `GLIBC_2.14' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0]
  2610: checking for version `GLIBC_2.2.5' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0]
  2610: checking for version `CXXABI_1.3' in file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] required by file /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0]
  2610: checking for version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' in file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] required by file /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0]
  2610: checking for version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' in file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] required by file /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0]
  2610: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error: version lookup error: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so) (fatal)
  2610: 
  2610: file=/home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so [0];  destroying link map
```

As you can see, it seems that the glibc version already loaded is in `/usr/lib` when my library loads, but my library needs to be loading the version in `~/.linuxbrew/lib`.

QLibrary is used to load the plugin as follows:

```
plug=new CPlugin(filename,pluginName);
int loadRes=plug->load();
```

I read in [The Inside Story on Shared Libraries and Dynamic Loading](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gbournou/CSE131/the_inside_story_on_shared_libraries_and_dynamic_loading.pdf) that "dynamically loaded modules are completely decoupled from the underlying application", and if that can be made to work correctly I'd like to reconfigure the loading process to solve the problem.

Here are the dependency lists found by ldd, which illustrates the dependency overlaps in different locations:

```
+ ldd /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc17af000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /home/hbr/.linuxbrew/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff5b9a32000)
    libm.so.6 => /home/hbr/.linuxbrew/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff5b9742000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/hbr/.linuxbrew/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff5b9531000)
    libc.so.6 => /home/hbr/.linuxbrew/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff5b91b9000)
    /home/hbr/.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.19/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff5b9f81000)
+ ldd /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/vrep
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc333f9000)
    liblua5.1.so (0x00007fc10e763000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fc10df28000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc10dd0a000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc10da06000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc10d7f0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc10d42b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc10d125000)
    libicui18n.so.54 (0x00007fc10ccb7000)
    libicuuc.so.54 (0x00007fc10c909000)
    libicudata.so.54 (0x00007fc10aedf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc10acdb000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc10aad9000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc10a8d1000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc10a5c9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc10e66d000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fc10a38b000)
+ LD_DEBUG=all /home/hbr/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_2_64_Linux/vrep
```

My launch script sets the first entry in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be `~/.linuxbrew/lib` but the application still picks up the system version first.

Also, for my own plugin library the RPATH is correct:

```
objdump -x libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so |grep RPATH
RPATH                /home/hbr/.linuxbrew/lib
```

**How can I resolve this version conflict so that my library loads correctly?**

Also, is this possible without changing the complete toolchain of either the parent application or my libary?

Comment: I suggest you rebuild your library using the system libraries.

Comment: @Anon Mail I appreciate the advice and would do that if it worked trivially, but I can't guarantee a given platform will support the dependency versions I need.

Comment: Can you build your library so it statically links it's dependent libraries?

Comment: Did you try to set `LIBRARY_PATH`? For an explanation see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13292386/4181011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will be specific to my use case, but many of the commands and settings can be generalized to other applications and configurations. I also have a [more detailed discussion of my debugging of this specific problem on the vrep forum](http://www.forum.coppeliarobotics.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4479).

First I changed vrep.sh to completely clear LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so it doesn't interfere with what's loading.

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Thanks to @fireant for the pointer, though unfortunately that link alone didn't solve my problem.

My first hints towards solving the problem were from this [stackoverflow post on rpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836330/is-there-a-way-to-inspect-the-current-rpath-on-linux) following commands from that post that let you see the current rpath:

```
objdump -x binary-or-library |grep RPATH

# Maybe an even better way to do it is the following:
readelf -d binary-or-library |head -20

# This second command above also lists the direct dependencies on other libraries followed by rpath.

# On ubuntu 15.04 someone had to use:
objdump -x binary-or-library |grep RUNPATH
```

The current 3.2.2 release of vrep has a very strange rpath, which I believe is because it may not be explicitly configured when vrep is built for release:

```
$ objdump -x vrep |grep RPATH
  RPATH                /home/marc/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64:/home/marc/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/
```

To solve the problem in my case I created a symlink from $VREPDIR/lib to where I wanted my libraries to be found in ~/.linuxbrew/lib, then [I changed the rpath of the vrep executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary) with the following commands:

```
VREPDIR=/path/to/vrep/executable
cd $VREPDIR
ln -s ~/.linuxbrew/lib $VREPDIR/lib
patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/lib' vrep
```

Note that the ld/rpath/patchelf systems understand $ORIGIN to be the directory where the vrep executable is located. Once I've run the above code, I have a new RUNPATH as follows (RPATH vs runpath may be due to version differences?):

```
$ objdump -x vrep |grep RUNPATH
  RUNPATH              $ORIGIN/lib
```

This solution isn't ideal and I'll probably need to fix it up because it is picking up the linuxbrew Qt installation as follows:

```
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fece8993000)
```

This may conflict with the API used by V-REP in the Qt shared library provided in the directory alongside vrep, especially as linuxbrew is updated. Nonetheless this solution works and vrep is loading 2 out of 3 .so libraries without crashing!  One improvement will be a few minor changes like those outlined below so that the libraries provided with vrep are still loaded.

Actually, the ideal solution for me would be one where vrep loads the system libraries, and the plugin loads the .linuxbrew libraries. I'm not sure that is possible and if it is it may require modifications to the vrep source/build.

While the application works with this solution there is some potential problems and I'm not sure if it is the ideal solution. Nonetheless I think it may be useful to others who encounter a similar issue with the applications they use.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I resolve this version conflict so that my library loads correctly?

That is not going to work for the basic, low-level libraries like the `libc` or `libstdc++`. The libraries manage number of global objects (memory management, threads, environment, locales, etc) and having several different versions of them in the same address space is a recipe for disaster. What's more, the STL classes of different `libstdc++` versions are not guaranteed to have the same binary layout in the memory. The `std::string` inside the application might not be the same as the `std::string` inside the library. Passing one from/to plug-in might cause a hard-to-debug crash. (The error message you get for the `libstdc++` is in part a safeguard against the situation.) That leads to the problem that (even if you link the `libstdc++` statically) the functions of your plug-in will not be able to accept or return STL classes as arguments/return values - only the basic C types.

Additionally, with dynamic loading, another hurdle is that Linux/UNIX linker uses a flat linear list of libraries with flat linear list of its symbols. And the libraries are identified by the internal `soname`, not the file name. The linker would bind the sought symbol to the first one, found by linear search through the list of libraries and their symbols. Libraries loaded at later time, would get most of their symbols satisfied from the libraries already loaded for the application itself. The libraries referenced by your plug-in might not even be looked at.

Overall, your choices are very limited:

- Static linking. Link the plug-in with static variants of the required libraries. But that does not work if you need to override the `libc` or `libstdc++`.
- Server/client approach. The plug-in library is a thin wrapper which only starts the server process, and then redirects all calls from application to plug-in via some RPC mechanism to this server application. This is the only reliable method known to me of resolving the library version conflicts. Since unlike a library, the application has more control over the dynamic linker (`rpath`, or in worst case with the `LD_PRELOAD`).

Generally, as was said by others before, you should always use the `libc` and `libstdc++` installed with the OS, releasing different builds for different OS variants if needed.

Comment: Citation needed for your wrong comments on the STL classes in libstdc++ (here the old version already has libstdc++.so.6, so it is not ancient).

Comment: Fortunately the API I'm using seems to stick to C interfaces across the plugin/application boundary, which is heavily integrated with lua as well, then provides c++ classes to make integration with those c apis easier.

Comment: @Marc Glisse "Citation needed" what comment precisely? "Wrong" is a bad identification. On the problems of binary compatibility of C++ classes/templates you can check the KDE's techbase: https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B GNU's STL library is famous for maintaining the long-term binary compatibility, yet it is also not forever: starting with GCC 5.x, the STL has new ABI. Most other compilers do not even bother with such long-term compatibility.

Comment: @AndrewHundt, then (1) use the OS's `libc`, (2) try static linking of the `libstdc++`. Try to test across the distros: `libc`'s binary interface is very stable, and unless you use some new functions, chances are that application/library compiled against new `libc` would also work with old `libc`. (But about the static GNU `libstdc++` you have to ask elsewhere - I haven't tried that myself. We have used static STLport for this purposes.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `rpath` can help you in this situation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082540), for an example.

Comment: I set the first entry in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be `~/.linuxbrew/lib` but it still picks up the system version first. Can I change the rpath for applications/libraries that have already been built? Also, for my own plugin library the RPATH is correct: `objdump -x libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so |grep RPATH`
  `RPATH                /home/hbr/.linuxbrew/lib`

Comment: Then maybe you can write a small test program, say test.c, that produces the same problem, but with small libraries that you can easier work with and version. Probably while working on that you see what's going wrong, or others here can work on the same code and help...

Comment: This didn't directly solve my problem, but it pointed me along the path with searching the right things, so I'm at least giving you my bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to build a shared library portable across different Linux distributions. This is tricky. Especially since you're dealing with C++.

Essentially, there are 3 libraries you need to deal with: `libc`, `libgcc_s`, and `libstdc++` (`libm` is not a huge deal, since you can always statically link against it).

The first one (`libc`) seems to be the biggest problem, since you can neither statically link against it, nor ship with your own version. But you don't need to if you pull a simple trick. The GNU C Library uses versioning of symbols and is backward compatible. You can rely on this. Just take a reasonably old version of `libc.so.6` (version 2.11 is old enough to make sure you'll work on virtually all distributions that are in use today, but you may want a newer version) and link dynamically against it. Don't ship it with your `libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so`, though. You're linking against it to make sure your `libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so` will dynamically link against (potentially newer) system-provided versions on target machines. You are relying on backward compatibility.

Now, if you were building an executable, you could just dynamically link against your own (`rpath`ed) versions of `libgcc_s` and `libstdc++`, and you would be ready to go. However, since you're building a shared library, you don't have such luxury. So you have two options.

First, you can try to pull the same trick as I've advised doing with `libc`. Dynamically link against an older version and see if it works. In theory, this should work, since `libstdc++` uses ELF symbols versioning as well (and sort of maintains backward compatibility). But I've tried doing similar things and faced several particularly nasty problems. So test rigorously (try throwing exceptions from your `libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so`, try passing short and empty `std::string`s around, try *everything*).

Alternatively, you can statically link against `libgcc_s` and `libstdc++`. This is what I recommend. This could be easily done with `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` options. But there is, of course, a catch. It is no longer safe for your `libv_repExtPluginSkeleton.so` to provide a C++ interface or call C++ functions from other libraries. The reason to this is that `libstdc++` is not particularly compatible between different versions.

So, summing all previously mentioned up, this is my recommendation:

- Dynamically link against an older version of `libc` to make sure you'll link against newer versions as well. Don't ship with it, though.
- Statically link against `libgcc_s` and `libstdc++` to not depend on them.
- Provide a C interface, since you have no other (portable) options.

Of course, this violates your wish not to change the toolchain you're using to build your library. You lose the C++ interface. And you also have to trade `libc` features for compatibility. But at least you *get* compatibility.

And yes, don't forget about licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a config file somewhere on your file system where the default modules folder is defined for your application. Vim and edit this path to be ~/.linuxbrew/lib. Re-run. If you still get module errors, **re-install the modules of the correct version** as your error messages show and copy the modules to the ~/.linuxbrew/lib path.  Lastly, **always examine permissions & ownership** on the modules and/or the module path. Perhaps your application is unable to pick up these modules due to a simple ownership/permissions issue.

Comment: can you explain a little more how to examine the permissions and ownership? Also what would reinstalling help with? All dependencies are fresh built and installed in the correct location they belong as far as I can tell, and the OS versions are also correct (for the OS)

Comment: Your first error message showed a problem with finding the version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21'. Do you have this installed? If not, you should install it. Run the command ls -la in the directory where the modules are stored to show the modules' owner/group and permissions. If the permissions do not include read or execute permissions for the user you are using for running your application, then the modules may not be loading correctly.

Comment: Looks like you found an answer above which works, though. Good work!